# How to filter by object's property in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

I have two array of objects as shown below:

```
$scope.countries = [
        {'id' : 1, 'country_name':'India'},
        {'id' : 10, 'country_name':'Australia'},
        {'id' : 2, 'country_name':'England'}
    ];
$scope.states = [
        {'state_id' : 1, 'state_name':'Delhi', 'country_id':{'id':1 ,'country_name':'India'}},
        {'state_id' : 5, 'state_name':'London', 'country_id':{'id':2 ,'country_name':'England'}},
        {'state_id' : 2, 'state_name':'Victoria', 'country_id':{'id':10 ,'country_name':'Australia'}}
    ];
```

I'm trying to filter the states based on the **id** inside the **country_id** object as shown below:

```
<select ng-model="sellerCountry" ng-options="item.id as item.country_name for item in countries" required>
    <option value="">Select Country</option>
</select>   

<select ng-model="sellerState" ng-options="item.id as item.state_name for item in states | filter : {country_id: { id : sellerCountry}, }" ng-disabled="!sellerCountry">
    <option value="">Select State</option>
</select>
```

Here, when i select **India** ( where **id** = 1) from the first select box, i should only get **Delhi** to be displayed in second select, but its  displaying **Delhi** (**country_id**.**id** = 1) and **Victoria**( **country_id**.**id** = 10 )

Need help to sort out this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default filters do `contains` search, you should make that filter to do strict comparison, by passing 3rd parameter to `true` to filter.

```
 ng-options="item.id as item.state_name for item in states
               | filter : {country_id: { id : sellerCountry} }: true"
```

[**Demo Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/WFOlVJXslMHewKWcPpWs?p=preview)